# How to tell if user has a voice remote with BrightScript?

Tags: roku, brightscript

Out channel wants to bring users to different experiences based on if their remote is Voice Enabled.

In the past, we can call ECP and find out about the remote info (as far as I remember). But with ECP out of the picture, are there any ways or workaround we can use to determine if user has a voice remote in hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since Roku OS 10.5, you can determine it by using

```
deviceInfo.hasFeature("handsfree_voice")
```

More info [here](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifdeviceinfo.md#hasfeaturefeature-as-string-as-boolean).